# POST request without NSURLConnectionDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, grand-central-dispatch, uiapplication

I would like to send POST request but without using delegate. I have to have everything in a block. I'm also didn't want to use `AFNetworking` for this simple task. Why? I have only one request in my app and doesn't feel like including 3-party library for this kind (i think easy) stuff.

I want to send `dispatch` block request at `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` method.

Comment: Why not use the delegate methods? Because you have a completion handler block to be called?

Comment: Becouse i'm using background fetching iOS7 feature, and want this method to be as clean as possible, don't separate it to another class and don't be messy in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:self.request
                                       queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
         {
         }
    }];
```